# Python csv writing

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm trying to write to a csv file using excel.

```
with open('Daily.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(["Sales Order;Company Name;Ship Date"])
```

This results in the following text being put into A1 and only A1.

Sales Order;Company Name;Ship Date

It appears the delimiter isn't working at all. I would like the data to be across three columns, not just one.

Comment: Here is the [docs of python csv.write](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

Answer (score 0):

use writer.writerow(["Sales Order", "Company", "Name", "Ship Date"])

Answer (score 0):

delimiter parameter of the csv.writer function doesn't set the delimiter for the data you want to write but for the file, so if you use the solution by Oleg you'll get a file with values delimited by ";". csv.writer.writerow needs the list of values.